# Chart Control Causing Full Postback

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have the following code, it was working fine if the chart control wasn't inside but as soon as I added the chart control it causes the whole page to refresh. Does anyone have an idea? I read through other similar questions suggest that the content need to be render into one single , if that's the cause what are my options? Thanks.

Regards,
Andy

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                <br />
                <br />

                <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="960px" Height="417px">
                    <series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </series>
                    <chartareas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </chartareas>
                </asp:Chart>

                <br />

                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, but was using Asp.net Routing.

Setting following property solved it.

ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" ...
            ImageType="Png" ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)"  ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" ../>
```

Also try
http://www.violato.net/blog/net/67-chart-image-is-not-showing-up-when-using-asp-net-charting-control